# using Js how can i set the value of two input fields as a start and end points for this function?

Tags: javascript

```
function createYears( start , end ) {
    "use strict";
    var years;
    document.write("<select>");
    for (years = start ; years <= end ; years = years + 1){
        document.write(`"<option>"`  + years +  `"</option>"`);
    }
    document.write("</select>");
}
```

Comment: Still not clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to have to input fields (of type number) that will be used as `start` and `end` values?

Comment: for the fuction when i call it using that code 
createYears(1990 , 2000); 
it creates a select box containing the years between 1990 and 2000 
i need these to values to be set by users by to input fields

Comment: i deleted the answer

Comment: You want two inputs field (one for `start` and one for `end`) that the user fill and then press a button for example and then the function get called using the values of those two inputs?

Comment: yup when he clicks on the button the function makes a select box using the first value as a start and the second as the end

Answer (score 0):

First create two input fields and give them IDs as follows:

```
<input type="number" id="start"/>
<input type="number" id="end"/>
```

Then create a button:

```
<button id="btn">Generate</button>
```

Then in your javascript file add an event listener to the button:

```
var btn = document.getElementById("btn"),              // get the button element
    startField = document.getElementById("start"),     // get the start input element
    endField = document.getElementById("end");         // get the end input element

btn.onclick = function() {                             // when the button is clicked
    var start = parseInt(startField.value),            // get the value of the start input (convert to number using parseInt)
        end = parseInt(endField.value);                // same for end

    createYears(start, end);                           // call createYears using the above values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand...you want to use the code and have an actual user interface to utilize it.

- **[Don't use `document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write)**
- Replaced `document.write` with `appendChild()` and `add()`
- Added a `<form>`, two `<input type='number'>`, and a `<button>`
- Because the **formControls** are in a `<form>` we can use **HTMLFormControlsCollection** which gives a shorter syntax to use for manipulating, referencing, etc.. of all formControls (i.e. inputs, outputs, select, buttons, etc.)
- In addition to what was previously mentioned, this will adjust to user input error when the start year is greater than the end year. If that happens this demo will swap the values. ex. *User data:* **Start:** `1972` **End:** `1968` the results would be as is *user data* is: **Start:** `1968` **End:** `1972`

### Reference

- [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)
- [**add()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/add)
- [**appendChild()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)
- [HTML **input type='number'** tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input)

### Demo

```js
var form = document.forms[0];

function createYears(start, end) {
  var sel = document.createElement('select');
  form.appendChild(sel);
  var yrs;
  if (start > end) {
    var temp1 = start;
    var temp2 = end;
    start = temp2;
    end = temp1;
  }
  for (yrs = start; yrs <= end; yrs = yrs + 1) {
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.textContent = yrs;
    opt.value = yrs;
    sel.add(opt);
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
button,
input,
select,
option {
  font: inherit
}

input {
  width: 6ch;
}
```

```html
<form id='calendar'>

  <label for='start'>Start: </label>
  <input id='start' type='number' min='1'>

  <label for='end'>End: </label>
  <input id='end' type='number' min='1'>

  <button type='button' onclick='createYears(start.valueAsNumber, end.valueAsNumber)'>Years</button><br><br>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter version:

```html
Start: <input id=y1 type=number> End: <input id=y2 type=number value=3e3>
<button onclick='var d = document, s = d.createElement("select"), y = y1.value; 
while (y <= y2.value) s.add(new Option(y++)); d.body.appendChild(s)'>Years</button>
```